# How can i make a simple form to calculate quantity x's a fixed rate?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I have a good understanding of how javascript works, but not how to implement it. I have a simple form that needs to calculate on the fly the price of x number of tickets at 75.00 each.  Let's say form id is quantity & total, with 75.00 being a rate. What would be the script to execute this and where should I add it.

The pertinent HTML is this:

```
<form id="docContainer" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" 
    novalidate="novalidate" data-form="preview">

    <label id="item4_label_0" ># of Tickets</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity" maxlength="254" data-hint="" name="quantity" required/>

    <label id="item13_label_0">Price Per Ticket</label>
    <input name="item_price" type="text" id="item_price" placeholder="75.00"
     maxlength="254" readonly data-hint="75.00"/>

    <label id="item14_label_0" >Total</label>
    <input name="total_price" type="text" id="total_price" maxlength="254" readonly/>

    <input type="submit" class="fb-button-special" id="fb-submit-button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: `total = amount * price ?` you don't really need a good understanding of anything to do that one ?

Comment: Where do I enter the code?

Comment: You know when people say don't use tables for layout..? For tabular forms just use a table - it's a whole lot cleaner with far less markup.

Comment: I use a simple form builder for most of my forms. I'm not a developer, but I am responsible for maintaining and advancing our charity's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs don't have ids so I've used their names. This is how you would do it with jQuery. I've forgotten how to write old school javascript, perhaps someone else can add to this.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('input[name="quantity"]').on('change keyup', function(){
        $('input[name="total_price"]').val($(this).val() * $('input[name="item_price"]').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

goes before

```
</body>
```

Edit: Added the necessary stuff for jQuery, but this can be done with regular js.

Comment: So, where would I put that snippet? In the <head>?

Comment: I've edited the code so show you how to include jQuery and where is best. http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#jQuery:_The_Basics

Comment: Got it!! Thanks. That is such a simple function. I need to just break down and learn jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>            

            window.onload = function() {
                var calculSumToString = function calculSumToString() {
                    totalField.value = (qtyField.value * itemPriceField.value).toFixed(2) + " $";
                };

                var totalField = document.getElementById('total_price');
                var qtyField = document.getElementById('quantity');
                var itemPriceField = document.getElementById('item_price');

                qtyField.onkeyup = calculSumToString;

                itemPriceField.onkeyup = calculSumToString;

            };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="docContainer" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" 
              novalidate="novalidate" data-form="preview">

            <label id="item4_label_0" ># of Tickets</label>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" maxlength="254" data-hint="" name="quantity" required/>

            <label id="item13_label_0">Price Per Ticket</label>
            <input name="item_price" type="text" id="item_price" value="75.00"
                   maxlength="254" readonly data-hint="75.00"/>

            <label id="item14_label_0" >Total</label>
            <input name="total_price" type="text" id="total_price" maxlength="254" readonly/>

            <input type="submit" class="fb-button-special" id="fb-submit-button" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then you do not have to grope anymore :D

Comment: My final question is in terms of number formatting (getting the decimal place to read to 2 places ($75.00) and also to get the $ to display. I know that is simple number formatting, but again not quite there yet on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Upon further review, the 75.00 needs to somehow also allow the dollar sign to be in there without messing up the function. If it's too much hassle, I can live without the dollar sign. But the decimal place would be nice.